# How many candidates are appearing for exam?

Tags: combinatorics

In exam there are 3 sections. each having 5 questions. A candidate has to choose at least one question from each section. Assuming everybody chooses different set of question, then how many candidates are there.

Now three questions (compulsory) can be chosen in $5^3$ ways and other two can be taken from 12 questions in C(12,2) ways. Hence total ways are $5^3 C(12,2)$. But my textbook states pretty small answer than this? where i have gone wrong

Comment: You over counted

Comment: Did you mean to say that each candidate has to answer to a total of five questions, with at least one taken from each of the three sections?

Comment: where does $5^3$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

> From each section one can select  in $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5}
>  \binom{5}{k}=2^5-1=31$ ways from $3$ questions if at
>   least one question has to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

> In exam there are 5 sections. each having 3 questions. A candidate has to choose at least one question from each section.

If the sections are $A,B,C,D,E$, then we need to pick at least $1$ question from each section, i.e. at least $5$ questions.

So:

> three questions (compulsory)

is irrelevant.

And:

> chosen in 5^3 ways and other two can be taken from $12$ questions in $\binom{12}{2}$ ways.

counts possibilities like

$AAABC, ABCDD$, etc..

which are not allowed, and doesn't count, for example:

$AAABCDE$.

Your answer is $16,500$, the actual answer is $7^5=16,807$.

Comment: i am so sorry. i typed question wrong